# Prove that if $n \mid 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k^{n-1}$ then $n$ is prime.

Tags: number-theory, conjectures, open-problem

How can I show that if $$n \mid 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k^{n-1}$$ then $n$ is prime?

I was able to prove that $n$ must be squarefree as follows: since $n \mid 1 + \sum_\limits{k=0}^{n-1} k^{n-1}$ then $\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n-1} k^{n-1} \equiv -1 \pmod n.$ Suppose some prime $p \mid n$, and let $q = n/p$. Now $\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n-1} k^{n-1} \equiv -1 \pmod p$, so
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k^{n-1} = \sum_{m=0}^{q-1}\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}(mp+k)^{n-1} \equiv \sum_{m=0}^{q-1}\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}k^{n-1} = q\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}k^{n-1} \equiv -1 \pmod p.$$
Since $-1$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, then so must be $q$, so since $p$ is prime we have $p \nmid q$, and thus $p \mid n$ but $p^2 \nmid n$.

I have not been able to show that $n$ must be prime. By reducing exponents using Fermat's Little Theorem, I can show that for every prime $p \mid n$ (again $q = n/p$) we have
$$q \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} k^{q-1} \equiv -1 \pmod p$$
but I am not sure how to deduce (if it is even possible) that for some $p \mid n$ we must have $q = 1$ (which would immediately imply $n = p$).

Comment: The question is [an open conjecture of Giuga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agoh%E2%80%93Giuga_conjecture)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms yeah, I mentioned that in my answer. I only recently learned that it was an open conjecture!

Comment: Very well, I simply thought that that remark would better be directly at the question, (so in a comment), such that the cursory reader gets aware of it without further ado. Even better would be the tag `open-problem` but I didn't find it (at MO they have such a tag) - (Ahh, and sorry - now I upvoted. Actually it was a problem which I liked very much some years ago and made a small essay on it)

Comment: Oh, that's a good point! Yeah, your comment is useful where it is :)

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT 2***: This answer is wrong, and in fact the question is [an open conjecture of Giuga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agoh%E2%80%93Giuga_conjecture).

---

In particular, the statement
$$\prod_{i \in I} q_i = n^{s-1} \prod_{i \not\in I} p_i$$
is simply completely false; it should instead say
$$\prod_{i \in I} q_i = n^{\left|I\right| - 1} \prod_{i \not\in I} p_i,$$
but then this does not allow us to simply the big sum to reach $1 \equiv 0 \pmod n$.

EDIT: the entire question may be readily generalized, since nowhere do we actually apply the fact that the problem involves powers of $k$. Indeed, suppose $f : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ is such that for every prime $p$, if $a \equiv b \pmod p$ then $f(a) \equiv f(b) \pmod p.$ If $n > 0$ is an integer such that
$$n \mid 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(k)$$
then $n = 1$ or $n$ is prime. To prove this, just use the proof I already have, but change every instance of $k^{n-1}$ to $f(k)$.

---

I think I have found a solution. Since I already proved that $n$ must be squarefree, let $n = p_1 p_2 \cdots p_t$ with all the $p_i$ distinct primes, and let $q_i = n / p_i$. Since
$$q_i \sum_{k=0}^{p_i-1}k^{q_i-1} \equiv -1 \pmod {p_i}$$
for all $i$, then for all $i$ there is some $m_i \in \mathbb Z$ such that
$$q_i \sum_{k=0}^{p_i-1}k^{q_i-1} + 1 = m_i p_i.$$
Then
$$\prod_{1 \leq i \leq s} \left(q_i \sum_{k=0}^{p_i-1}k^{q_i-1} + 1\right) = \prod_{1 \leq i \leq s} m_i p_i = n \prod_{1 \leq i \leq s} m_i,$$
so
$$\prod_{1 \leq i \leq s} \left(q_i \sum_{k=0}^{p_i-1}k^{q_i-1} + 1\right) \equiv 0 \pmod n.$$ Assume $s > 1$ (so $n$ is not prime). We may turn the ugly product above into an even more ugly sum of smaller products:
$$\begin{align*}
0 &\equiv \prod_{1 \leq i \leq s} \left(q_i \sum_{k=0}^{p_i-1}k^{q_i-1} + 1\right) \pmod n \\
&= \sum_{I \subseteq \{1, \ldots, s\}} \left(\prod_{i \in I} q_i \sum_{k=0}^{p_i-1}k^{q_i-1}\right) \left(\prod_{i \not\in I} 1\right) \\
&= \sum_{I \subseteq \{1, \ldots, s\}} \left(\prod_{i \in I} q_i \sum_{k=0}^{p_i-1}k^{q_i-1}\right).
\end{align*}$$
Now consider a product $\prod_{i \in I} q_i$ where $\emptyset \neq I \subseteq \{1, \ldots, s\}$. Since $q_i = n / p_i$, then
$$\begin{align*}
\prod_{i \in I} q_i &= \prod_{i \in I} \prod_{j \neq i} p_j \\
&= \prod_{i \in I} p_i^{s - 1} \prod_{i \not\in I} p_i^s \\
&= \left(\prod_{i \in I} p_i\right)^{s-1} \left(\prod_{i \not\in I} p_i\right)^s \\
&= n^{s-1} \prod_{i \not\in I} p_i.
\end{align*}$$
Now the big ugly sum becomes less ugly:
$$\begin{align*}
0 &\equiv \sum_{I \subseteq \{1, \ldots, s\}} \left(\prod_{i \in I} q_i \sum_{k=0}^{p_i-1}k^{q_i-1}\right) \pmod n \\
&= \left(\prod_{i \in \emptyset} q_i \sum_{k=0}^{p_i-1}k^{q_i-1}\right) + \sum_{\emptyset \neq I \subseteq \{1, \ldots, s\}} \left(\prod_{i \in I} q_i \sum_{k=0}^{p_i-1}k^{q_i-1}\right) \\
&= 1 + \sum_{\emptyset \neq I \subseteq \{1, \ldots, s\}} \left(\prod_{i \in I} q_i \sum_{k=0}^{p_i-1}k^{q_i-1}\right) \\
&= 1 + \sum_{\emptyset \neq I \subseteq \{1, \ldots, s\}} \left(n^{s-1} \prod_{i \not\in I} p_i \prod_{i \in I} \sum_{k=0}^{p_i-1}k^{q_i-1}\right) \\
&= 1 + n^{s-1} \sum_{\emptyset \neq I \subseteq \{1, \ldots, s\}} \left(\prod_{i \not\in I} p_i \prod_{i \in I} \sum_{k=0}^{p_i-1}k^{q_i-1}\right) \\
&\equiv 1 \pmod n.
\end{align*}$$
Since $0 \equiv 1 \pmod n$, then $n = 1$.

Therefore if $n \mid \sum_\limits{k=0}^{n-1} k^{n-1}$ then $n$ is one or prime.

Comment: Hmm, it might be a not-too-difficult problem to show the primeness for the given assumption. If I recall right, then the open part of the problem is, to show that it also holds for the compositeness in the contrary of the assumption, so that in fact in the question can be written an ***IFF*** instead an ***IF*** . *(But I'm not sure about this at the moment)*

Comment: Possibly your answer is not "wrong" but only "insufficient" or "incomplete"? (Didn't read it right through)

Comment: I tried fixing this "proof" after finding my mistake, but found I couldn't get around the lack of nice assumptions that I had mistakenly taken earlier. I suppose in some sense it is incomplete, and not wrong, but on the other hand it is woefully incomplete, and I'm not sure salvagable...

Comment: Hmm, I think, if it is at least a proof for the half-side of the problem, it might have an orientating/introducting character and might thus be helpful for self-study/self-students ...